# Newsfeed Posts Disappear Suddenly

Tags: user-profile-service, mysite, newsfeed

My post in the news-feed disappear after 1 min and trying to change the cache for the appfabric but it's not working and i stuck here how i can change this setting for my newsfeed ?

i try the solution by `Stop-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance` and restart the iis
but still disappear , i using only SharePoint 2013 and the sql server installed  on the same server , the newsfeed suddenly start disappear before it's working normally

Comment: after restarting the instance...did you post something? what you mean by disappear, any error on screen?

Comment: i mean by disappear , after 1 min the newsfeed will hide on the screen , by refreshing the page it's will appearing again  but after 1 min will hide again

Comment: any error? check the event log and uls logs for any clue...meanwhile run these and see the status of cache...Use-CacheCluster

Get-CacheHost

Comment: HostName : CachePort    Service Name            Service Status Version Info
--------------------    ------------            -------------- ------------
                        AppFabricCachingService          DOWN           3 [3,3[1,3]


The services down

Answer (score 0):

Your issue with distributed cache. NewsFeed totally depend upon on the DC, if the DC is down you will lose all the post as well as newsfeed stop working. You have to make sure that DC is up and running.

Follow this [blog to repair](http://krossfarm.com/?p=73) the Cachhost on the server.

Comment: $instanceName =”SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService”
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq
$instanceName -and ($_.server.name) -eq $env:computername}
$s.delete()

Running the delete giving me this error You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: oh their is typo...you should run this $serviceInstance.delete()

Comment: i did the same but still the newsfeed hiding after few seconds , only if i refresh the page it will came back , this's really strange the service up and i did the same things .

Comment: how many server in the farm? which browser you are using? any error in the uls logs or event log?

Comment: one server for sharepoint and SQL server, IE 11 ,Uls logs no error

Comment: still cache host looks as up or down.....you are still losing the posts or just dissappear and re appear after refresh

Comment: The cache host it's  up and the posts reappear after refresh

Comment: then it look like  more browser issue...try with different browser and also login from different machine.

Comment: same :( 

there's error now in the Uls
Event 5586 (SharePoint Foundation) of severity 'Error' occurred 2 more time(s) and was suppressed in the event log

Comment: Can you reboot the server? If not pro....what is error details?

Comment: The  error details :

Unknown SQL Exception 1101 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.  Could not allocate a new page for database 'WSS_Logging' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

Comment: still same after reboot :(

Comment: I find one error :  This Distributed Cache host may cause cache reliability problems .

Explanation : This Distributed Cache service on this Distributed Cache host has been stopped but not unregistered from the farm. In order to avoid reliability issues, it is recommended that a Distributed Cache host with a stopped Distributed Cache service be unregistered from the farm.

Comment: In this completely stop n remove the DC and the start it....

Comment: and this will not affect the sharepoint ?
when it's done i will send u

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24363/discussion-between-abdullah-and-waqas-sarwar-mcse).

Comment: Sorry I can't chat as I m out of office.

Comment: Still same , i don't know if it there anyoption to increase the timer for newsfeed

Comment: @Abdullah are you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I noticed that the name in the IE tab would change which led me to believe it was a problem with the page and not the web part. I recreated the page, and it worked. The page that was initially giving me issues was the default home page.